# Surpress specified errormessages temporarely using ib_insync with python

Tags: python, interactive-brokers, ib-insync

I'm using ib_insync and Python and I would like to capture those cases where secType has not been specified (but only symbol, exchange and maybe currency).

The code below tries to find a valid secType but by doing that IB generates messages 200 and / or 321 at the console.
I would like to surpress those messages ONLY while performing these tests.

```
            elif (typeSec == ""):       # Type of contract not specified by the caller
                secTypes = [ "", "IND", "FOREX", "OPT", "FUT", "CRYPTO", "STK"]
                # Try various possibilities
                # IB will generate errors 321 and 200 for each failure
                for i in secTypes:
                   contract = Contract(symbol= symbol, exchange= exchange, currency= currency, secType=i)
                   if not (contract == None):
                        try:
                            self.ib.qualifyContracts(contract) # Fill the contract with missing info (Remark: self.ib is an ib-connection stored in a class)
                            if not ((contract.secType == None) or (contract.secType == "")):
                                typeSec = contract.secType
                                # Eventually a valid contract has been found, maybe the right one
                                break
                        except:
                            contract = None

            if (contract == None):
                print("Create contract for sectype= ", typeSec, " has not been implemented yet")
```

How can achieve this

This method could be used to gather all valid possibilities and let the user chose the one (s)he wants.

In a post I saw it is possible to surpress specific IB-errros/warnings and also errorahandlers for the whole program but that's not what I'm looking for: I would just like to turn off those messages for this small part of the code.